# Eclipse won't delete files

Tags: eclipse, ant

I've got an ANT project with libs managed by ivy (they are under lib_managed). Eclipse is using the jars to. Probelm is: if I try to update the directory ant refuses to delete it because eclipse holds on to the jars in its classpath. Even if I update (empty) eclipses classpath I can't delete the files. If anyone had the same problem and found a solution I would be thankfull for an answer.

Regards, Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a solution, but a workaround. I experience Eclipse keeping locks on files quite often in different contexts. I suggest using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).

Comment: Good idea, but sadly my client doesn't like anyone to install any software not certified by their IT ... ;-) I'm lucky I can use cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is on Windows. Use the Process Explorer to figure out who is locking the files. Eclipse shouldn't keep a lock; maybe you have the code running in the debugger (hanging in a breakpoint). Use the list of open files and the properties to figure out which Java program is keeping the lock on the files.

If it's really Eclipse, try to upgrade to a newer version of Eclipse or close the project when you need to update the dependencies with ivy.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is on windows. Cleaning the workspace and restarting eclipse solved the problem. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Cleaning the workspace and restarting eclipse may solve the problem. But in real development environment i don't think its a good idea to restart eclipse whenever you need to build a jar.